# How many quadratic polynomials exist given the two zeroes? ($1$ or $\infty$)

Tags: polynomials, roots

I was reading some book which had this question:

> **Q.** The number of [quadratic] polynomials having zeros $-2$ and $5$ is:
>
> (A) 1
>   (B) 2
>   (C) 3
>   (D) More than three?
>
> **Sol.** (A) 1.

But according to me there should be an infinite amount of polynomials. All these polynomials have the zeroes $-2$ and $5$:

\begin{align*}
(x+2)(x-5)&=0,\\
2(x+2)(x-5)&=0,\\
3(x+2)(x-5)&=0,\\
4(x+2)(x-5)&=0,\\
5(x+2)(x-5)&=0, \text{etc}.
\end{align*}

According to me, if we are given the two zeroes of a quadratic polynomial, then we can find $\infty$ polynomials with those two zeroes. I do not know why the answer $1$ is given in the book. Maybe it is a misprint? *So am I right or the book is right?*

Clarification: I just wanted to ask if these polynomials are considered to be the same or different.

Comment: You are right. Though check that the book may have made a note somewhere that only monic polynomials are being considered.

Comment: @DavidPeterson There is no note. There are only Question and answers in the book.

Comment: All those are equivalent; constants in $\mathbb{Q}$ are units in $\mathbb{Q}[X]$

Comment: @FireGarden What is $\mathbb{Q}[X]$?

Comment: @FireGarden: They are equivalent (modulo the implied equivalence relation), but they are still distinct.

Comment: The ring of polynomials with coefficients from $\mathbb{Q}$. I guess my comment isn't particularly useful to you, then.

Comment: You are perfectly right (except if there is a restriction for a coefficient).

Comment: I'd also add negative multiples, like $-2(x+2)(x−5)$ or $-17(x+2)(x−5)$ :).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are right, the book is mistaken (perhaps they are taking polynomials which are constant multiples of each other as equal).